# Do the indexes from the phpmyadmin MySQL need to be the same in Sphinx

Tags: mysql, database, indexing, localhost, sphinx

I am currently trying to figure out how to set up a search database on `localhost` which is set up with `sphinx` which I have no experience with, nor did I create this crazy database and scripting I have to work with. I successfully have install `sphinx` on the computer and it connects well. Now my question is do I need to set up the same `index` fields as it was set up in `phpMyAdmin`?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.

You setup sphinx to index the column(s) you need to be able to search. They dont need to match mysql indexes at all.

But if you recreating a search that used to use the mysql full-text indexes, then you would create the sphinx index on the same column(s) plus any additional columns you need to be able to filter, group or sort by.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Now I have some investigations to do, lol :-)

Comment: One more thing. I just found out that the site was using an older version like 0.0.9 or something. I installed a newer verion on the local. Does that matter?

Comment: 0.0.9 ? probably 0.9.* ;-) the next version have really improve performance but also added a lot of feature.